# illegal call for function in lisp: being able to make functions call each other

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I have to do a algorithm in order to derivate an expression with Lisp. To do so, my teacher told me do a function for each operator and a more global function in order to handle the operator.

So I got a main function deriv calling different function. Each sub function will recal the main deriv function.

Here's my code, I got an illegal call because the main deriv function is defined later in the code. If i put the deriv function before, i get an error concerning Deriv_addSous (and all other sub func). I9 didn't include the other funct since it's not important for my issue.

How can I handle this error, is there any way for the function to be able to call each other?

Thanks :)))

```lisp
(defun deriv_addSous(terme var)
    (list (car terme) (deriv (cadr terme ) var)(deriv (caddr terme) var))
)


(defun deriv(expr var)
    ; utiliser une liste et reutiliser la fonction du TD1 pour traiter chaque élément seul
    (if (atom expr) (deriv_term expr var))
    (cond (((equal (car expr) '+) (deriv_addSous expr var))
            ((equal (car expr) '-)(deriv_addSous expr var))
            ((equal (car expr) '*)(deriv_mult expr var))
            ((equal (car expr) '/)(deriv_div expr var))
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: You have a syntax error in the function DERIV. The syntax for COND is violated. There is an extra level of parentheses around the COND clauses.

Comment: Your bug report is not complete. One can't reproduce it.

For a bug report you need to show what you did, the actual error report and tell us what Lisp implementation you are using.

Comment: Lose the habit of writing parentheses as if they were block delimiters, like curly braces in certain other languages. Lisp doesn't really have the structure that the layout suggests.

Comment: Also, your `if`-conditional is wrong - the value of `(if (atom expr) (deriv_term expr var))` is just ignored and discarded. The `cond` should be its other branch and not left outside.

Comment: Formatting wise, should also be using kebab-case identifiers instead of snake_case - the latter looks really odd in lisp, and put spaces between arguments... `(defun deriv-addSous (terme var) ...)`

Comment: Why is there and `if` form _and_ a `cond` form? Why not a single `cond` instead?

Comment: @adabsurdum To me, it looks like `if (atom(expr)) return deriv_term(expr, var); switch (car(expr)) { case '+': return deriv_addSous(expr, var); case '-': ... }` translated into Lisp.

Comment: What you imagine to be the problem isn't the problem. Both your function definitions appear together in the same file. By the time either the `deriv_addSous` or the `deriv` function is called, both of them are defined.  The file compiler doesn't require them to be defined in order.    Macros have to be defined before they are used, because they have to be called in order to process the definitions which use them.

Comment: The very specific problem is that your first condition is `((equal (car expr) '+) (deriv_addSous expr var))`, which tries to apply `(equal (car expr) '+)` as a function to  `(deriv_addSous expr var)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a syntax error in the function DERIV. The syntax for COND is violated. There is an extra level of parentheses around the COND clauses.

If a function is not known at compile time, that's not an error in Common Lisp. Just a warning.